# how to redirect a html page to another website which is hosted in google drive urlshorten by gdriv.es

Tags: google-drive-api, url-shortener

I am new to this.
Can any one tell me why my HTML page which is hosted in Google Drive, cannot redirect to a particular webpage while URL is shortened in [GDRIV](http://gdriv.es/) .
my html file content was

```
<html>
<body>

<p>you will be redirected soon.</p>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://examplesite.com">

</body>
</html>
```

I shared the Folder to the public and it was working fine, but the URL was bitty flabby like
https@://googledrive.com/host/0BXXXXXXXXXXXXXMGM/site.html
So I shortened the URL with the help of [GDRIV](http://gdriv.es/)
and i got a decent short URL something like
http@://gdriv.es/XXXX/site.html
But the redirecting function is no more working while using  the shorten URL and work fine with that clumsy URL
Can any one tell me why this happen and well I think it is irrelevant to ask you tat ' Can i use PHP coding in Google drive hosted sites? '

Answer (score 0):

It works. I did same thing in above example you provided and it did redirect my gdriv.es shortened address to redirected website. 
Of course I assume you are aware of typo you made by adding @ in your URL.
If it still doesn't work for you there is a "Send Feedback" link at the bottom of [gdrive.es](http://gdriv.es) main page.
Fill that form and I'm sure they'll check that problem.

For your second question: No, you can not use PHP or any other server side scripting language on Google Drive Hosted Web Sites.
However you can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) which works under Google Drive and it uses Javascript language. You can do many things with GAS, one of them provides you a facility similar to PHP: [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service).

One caveat though: It has a javascript sanitization mechanism called [CAJA](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-caja). Meaning you can't just run any javascript code you like. Check last link for restrictions.